# SQL Server Express 2017 Database Mail Silent error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-express, database-mail, windows-server

I have made an installation of a development environment in VMWare that contains:

- Windows Server 2016
- SQL Server Express 2017

The objective is to perform migration tests of a base that is currently in:

- Windows Server 2003
- SQL Server Express 2008 R2

In the old environment (2008 R2) I use Database Email to send emails without problems.

I have made the same steps to send emails in the same environment.

Everything seems to work well. The emails appear in `sysmail_sentitems`. No problem in `sysmail_event_log`.

However, the emails do not arrive.

But there is no error. Tests that I did:

- I disabled the firewall
- I disabled Windows Defender
- I connected with Telnet
- I tried different email profiles

Everything seems to go, but the mail does not arrive and there are no errors.

Any idea what I can investigate?

Answer (score 4):

Database mail is [not included](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-2017) with SQL Server *Express* editions. SQL Agent is another feature that is also reserved for paid versions.

Since this is a development environment, I would install [SQL Server Developer](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) which comes with all of the Enterprise features for free. You just can't store production data or use it in production. This allows you to test apples to apples.

> SQL Server 2017 Developer is a full-featured free edition, licensed
>   for use as a development and test database in a non-production
>   environment

Comment: I know that. But it has always been possible to install without the assistant and use without problems. Please, this question can be answered by forgetting that it is Express. The important thing is to detect the communication problem. Thank you.

Comment: You can’t use database mail with express. I’m not sure what’s unclear about that. You can use developer or standard or any paid version. You’re going to have to show us how you used database mail with express before as its never been available in recent versions. There is no communication problem.

Comment: Yes you can. It Is not oficial supported but you can.

Comment: Ok, if that's the case can you show us? By the state of your question, it seems like you haven't figured this out--so do you have any documentation supporting this or a verifiable and repeatable example? I'm sure Microsoft would like to know too. Please, show us...@jpussacq

Comment: There are hundreds of articles that explain how it is configured. In fact it is very simple. You just have to use the functions provides by MS http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/02/sending-mail-using-sql-server-express-edition/ or https://www.veryiz.com/2017/configure-sql-database-email/

Answer (score -4):

Finally I have solved the problem by changing the name of the **computer**. After looking for differences between the VMs, I noticed checking the headers of the emails, that the name of the computer appeared in the header. I changed it and it started to work. As if in some way, that name would be blocked ...